# Erro PHP - Try_Catch

Tags: php, try-catch, syntax-error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\validar_cad_usuario\face.php on line 65

Meu Projeto ta ai se alguém  poder ajudar, Agradeço!

```
    try {
                 // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
                $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name, picture, email');
                $user = $response->getGraphUser();
                //var_dump($user);
                $result_usuario = "SELECT id, nome, email FROM usuario WHERE email='".$user['email']."' LIMIT 1";
                $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
                if($resultado_usuario){
                    $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $row_usuario['id'];
                        $_SESSION['nome'] = $row_usuario['nome'];
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $row_usuario['email'];
                        header("Location: administrativo.php");
                    }
                }               
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: É erro de sintaxe. Sem o código nem tem como dizer onde está o problema.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10sL8xxdUv-cTkwmwyXmoSqLrawnDNcMa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: esse ai é o projeto se puder dar uma olhada e me ajudar

Comment: Não faltou uma `}` do try?

Comment: pode conferir, ela está la

Comment: consegui resolver, o problema era a chave do if la em cima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provavelmente esqueceu de um ponto e virgula:

eis um exemplo de [Exceções](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php)

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Divisão por zero.');
    }
    return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exceção capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Execução continua
echo "Olá mundo\n";
?>
```

Comment: pode olhar ai, mas conferi várias vezes e não encontrei erro

Comment: eu baixei e olhei, a estrutura não esta como a da minha resposta. por exemplo no começo tem um try e 2 catchs

Comment: eu sei, mas consegui resolver